# Why the recent spike in the number of questions?

Tags: discussion

I suppose nobody failed to notice the current question deluge; or the dearth that went before it. In case you have, here are numbers:

### Average number of questions per week

```
              4 weeks         4 weeks          4 weeks         4 weeks         Current week
Weeks       Dec 29-Jan 25   Jan 26-Feb 22   Feb 23-Mar 21   Mar 22-April 18     April 19-25
Questions       12.25           8.25            8.25             6.0                23
```

Or if you visit [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language) from time to time you will have noticed that the average number of questions per day reached a low of 0.8 a week ago and now stands at 2.1. Of course this is all very welcome, but does anyone have an explanation for it? I want to believe it's not just a random spike. After all we had basically as many questions this week as in the previous four weeks combined; and more questions than in any other week since the first week of September. And this after twelve absolutely dismal weeks.

I don't know what may have caused this sudden change. Perhaps someone has been working behind the scenes, and the site has become more visible? The number of visits to the site is at an all time high too, but not that much higher than in the previous weeks. It has been climbing gradually over time. So, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed the number of visitors has been rising steadily. The number of questions is so low that it's difficult to tell if it's a random spike or not. It's likely that more visitors will bring more questions, but the number of visitors for the Spanish site is 6 times larger and they sit at only 2.7 questions/day.